# Convert Persian currency text to its numeric equivalent

Tags: java, function, persian

How I can convert a Normal Persian currency text like this :

```
"یکصد هزار"
```

To This Type:

```
"100000"
```

In English view I want to convert "two hundred thousand" to "200000"

Comment: Are u looking for ascii value of each chars? What do you expect for english String e.g what shall be output for "hello world"

Comment: You need to converting `farsi` charset to  `hex` OR `byte` type

Comment: No. I guess the word says "hazaar" means thousand. Probably he wants the "numeric" value of  the "text"

Comment: As you said, I want to convert word "hazaar" to "1000", In English view I want to convert "two hundred thousand" to "200000".

Comment: are you look for ascii code to any key??

Comment: No, I edited my post with better explanation.

Comment: @SaeedBibak That will be some task to do. Because thousand can also be represented in ten hundreds as well. So you need to build the dictionary of all such words and convert :(

Comment: Isn't any thing like this even in English that could help me ?
I search a lot, but couldn't find useful  things.

Comment: I think this is difficult in any language. It really depends on the amount of flexibility you need. To parse "two hundred thousand two hundred and two" requires not just recognizing the word "two", but that the word has different functions in different places in the text. So you'd need to construct some sort of parser with grammar rules. There might already be some library to do this in Java, but I don't know of one. I presume you would have similar problems in Persian, but with a different grammar and dictionary. Good luck :)